# How to create global variables in javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to create a button on a catalogue page so that once tapped the user goes to the permalink with a textarea visible in order to write a caption (the default of the permalink is with the textarea hidden).

I'm trying to find a way of passing global variables between pages, i would like to avoid cookies, local storage for such a simple matter, also I cannot pass special parameters to the permalink such as &txt=open.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass variables "between pages" in "a single page app"?

Comment: Then you have no way to achieve this. Different page means different execution context, no way to share variable if you don't use some storage.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but the point is that if I set a var on the onclick event of the button (apparently) after the new page is loaded via ajax this var is undefined.

Comment: @xdazz technically it's the same page, it only injects the contents of the loaded page inside the DOM

Comment: @sathia Then you could use global variable, right?

Comment: @xdazz that's what I'm asking, I don't know why it doesn't work! it should, but it doesn't

Comment: You have only one domain, right ? If not, here's your problem.

Comment: @sathia So how can we know the reason if you just tell us it doesn't work ?

Comment: yes, of course. maybe it's a stupid error I'm making somewhere. I'll debug again and post here my findings

Comment: now I'm working on the project that where we using [AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). It is best way to resolve your question.... -David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way is localStorage. You don't want but you have to:P

Set:
window.localStorage.setItem("nameofvariable",value);
And get:
window.localStorage.getItem("nameofvariable");

Set value on the first page, and you can use it on another as long as you wish. Try read docs:
[PhoneGap Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

You are interested in content at the bottom of the page.

If you  don't use phonegap, write the same code, and delete "window.". It should work, and solve your problem.

Comment: Apparently it's the easier way to do it. I'll try this way